# How to write client server application with web sockets using jetty server with embedded wtp plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, jquery, eclipse, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am new to jetty. I want to use jetty web socket in my application. I tried my best but unable to find a good tutorial how to write server and client. I want to write client in jquery and server in JAVA EE 1.6.
I used http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty_WTP_Plugin/Jetty_WTP_Websocket_Wizard
but there is some library error on **private Outbound outbound;** So Please help me by providing a good tutorial having implementation in eclipse, jetty and jdk 1.6.
I will be really very very thankful to you all.

Comment: I hope this tutorial will help you. http://angelozerr.wordpress.com/about/websockets_jetty/

Answer (score 0):

The wtp wizards have not kept up with the latest released drafts (nor the final release of the spec) of the websocket protocol.

for an example of a websocket client and server in jetty take a look at the cometd project, they have a fully working setup with it.

http://cometd.org/

Alternately take a look at the test cases in jetty-websocket itself for other examples of working client and server examples in java.